# C++: WinAPI обработка нажатий мыши

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Получил задание : при нажатии ЛКМ(Левой Кнопкой Мыши) - выводить сообщение в окно о нажатии этой клавиши при нажатии ПКМ(Правой кнопкой мыши) - стирать одно последнее сообщение,при двойном нажатии ЛКМ(Левой Кнопкой Мыши) - выводить сообщение о двойном нажатии, при двойном нажатии ПКМ - стирать 2 последних сообщения. Не могу придумать, как это реализовать,прошу помощи.

Comment: Например, используйте массив или список строк-сообщений. На WM_LBUTTONDOWN добавляете сообщение в конец списка и вызываете InvalidateRect(), на WM_RBUTTONDOWN удаляете последний элемент из списка и вызываете InvalidateRect(). Аналогично обрабатываете двойные нажатия (WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK ). На WM_PAINT построчно выводите содержимое списка в окно, например с помощью функции TextOut()...

Comment: ...А ещё лучше вместо строк использовать целочисленные коды сообщений. Так как у вас их всего два вида, то например 0 может означать однократное нажатие ЛКМ, а 1 - двойное нажатие ЛКМ.

Comment: написал такой код case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
  y -= 20;
  hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
  TextOut(hdc, 0, y, r_str, _tcsclen(r_str));
  ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
  break;
 case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
  hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
  TextOut(hdc, 0, y, l_str, _tcsclen(l_str));
  ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
  y += 20;
  break;

Comment: тут в общем и целом пишется строка при нажатии ЛКМ , а при нажати ПКМ возвращается на предыдущий y и презаписывается строка на пустую

Comment: но у меня поблема с даблкликом , я написал кейс перед одинарным но у меня все равно заходит в одинарный